# Using logic when working with Sikuli plug-in in Java (NetBeans)

Tags: java, image, swingworker, sikuli, scanning

first time post here!

So, I've have been trying to solve a (hopefully) rather simple issue that I'm having with my code.

So, the scenario is that I'm making Sikuli search for two images, and execute different actions based on what it finds.
A example of the code looks like following:

```
int x=2;
int y;

while(x>1){
    if(s.exists(victory.similar((float)0.70)) != null){ 
       y=1;
    }
    else if(s.exists(defeated.similar((float)0.70)) != null){
        y=2;
    }
    else{
    x++;}
}
```

But the problem that I am currently having, is the fact that this works *only* when it find the first alternative - being blind to the other one.

This is happening over several scenarios within the code, of similar structure.

A detail worth mentioning is probably also the fact that I am running this code with SwingWorker, yet still I do not really see any reason for this to influence the code due to the rest of this part of the script working well (as long it is not a part like the one mentioned above!).

Thank You in advance for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

the other alternative will be seen just if the first (**false**) 
if you want to check two **if** statements  you must delete else word

Answer (score 0):

Changing the script to

```
if(s.exists(victory.similar((float)0.70)) != null){ 
       y=1;
    }
    if(s.exists(defeated.similar((float)0.70)) != null){
        y=2;
    }
    else{
    x++;}
```

Did not solve the issue, for whatever reason the script stays blind...